# Get request data from batch request Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code:

```
       GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(
                GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject jsonObject,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, response.toString()); //Prints user information
                            }
                        }),
                GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        "me/taggable_friends",
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                                Log.i(TAG, graphResponse.toString()); //Prints the taggable friends
                            }
                        })
        );
        batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch graphRequests) {
                // Application code for when the batch finishes

                //Get both friends and user information here?


            }
        });
        batch.executeAsync();
```

How can I get access to both the taggale friends and user information Inside `onBatchCompleted`? The `graphRequests` does not contain the taggable friends and the user information.

Comment: Batch requests return JSON data, that contains an array with a response code, headers and body for each single request contained in the batch, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#simple

Comment: @CBroe: When I print out the response inside newGraphPathRequest, I can see the names of the taggable friends. When I print out the response inside onBatchCompleted, I can't see the names.

Comment: @Bryan, you need to be more specific about what you *do* see as part of `graphRequests`. Perhaps you can edit the question and add a dump of the variable's string representation.